# div wont stay in the same place?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Hi guys any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on my website and I have a div that contains my login form that on the click of a button changes it to my registration form.

The problem is that when the page first loads the form is in 1 place. When I click the button it moves right. I can than swap backward and forward between forms without any problem and the form stays in 1 place.

http://www.legaleyealpha.webatu.com/v2/index.html

If you click the blue button around the eye at the top this will change the form. I havnt finished designing this part yet.

this is the link to my index page and you can see the problem. I even tried making a 3rd div that moves the form further right to start with but it still wont work.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be a lot easier to describe your problem, and for others to help, if you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — you might even find that it doing this, you work out the solution yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see all the positioning is done in the styling. Your `#background2` declaration (which is what you start with) has `left: 242px` while the `#background1` and `#background` you use afterwards have `left: 400px`

Answer (score 0):

You have three divs we're interested in. This is what they look like on page load:

```
<div class="login" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="startup"></div>
<div class="signup" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Then, after clicking the "signupbuttonswap" button, they look like this:

```
<div class="login" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="startup" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="signup" style="display: block;"></div>
```

And after clicking it one more time, they look like this:

```
<div class="login" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="startup" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="signup" style="display: none;"></div>
```

So your problem is less about a div moving inexplicably, and more about the fact that **you're hiding and showing two different divs** that occur in two different places.

My question, then, is why is the login form duplicated in two different places?

## EDIT

Basically, your div.startup seems to be unnecessary. Get rid of that, and on page load make the div.login visible, and you should be good.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the replies. The 1st div I just put in to try to get it to load where I moves to after a button click. If I remove it then the same thing happens. I loads div1 to the left. Click the button it jumps right and then you can swap and it stays in the same place

Comment: Hi guys I have amended as suggest to show you why i added the 3rd Div in the first place. As you can see it still loads to the left and jumps on button click to them remain in place. Any other ideas?

Comment: For what it's worth, in Firefox, the div appears in the same place. On Safari, it jumps around.